# Amazon Glacier - know filename corresponding to archive ID or Tree hash

Tags: amazon-glacier

How can I list the filename of contents stored in Amazon Glacier Vault using Archive ID or treehash? I have the Vault inventory which has Archive ID's and Treehash. How can one find out the filename associated?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on client software that you use to upload files to Amazon Glacier. Usually file name is encoded in ArchiveDescription field of inventory output. Contact software vendor for exact format of ArchiveDescription used.